# Formatting text from MySQL

Tags: php, html

I've been wondering how could I apply different styles to text that is taken from MySQL db. Let's assume the user makes a blog post with 5 paragrphs in the content field. When I add the post to the database, it is saved as one continuous string, right? Now, when I want to make the new post visible on the main page, the text is also shown as one continuous string, even though the user made 5 separate paragraphs.

I tried to make a little research about the topic, but didn't find anything useful. How are the paragraphs added when taking the text from the mysql database? It would be interesting to know, how big blogging sites (or even StackOverflow) deal with such things. I'm open to all interesting ideas and references!

Comment: This has nothing to do with MySQL (and definitely nothing to do with JavaScript). What happens if "the string" came from a literal in code? In any case, *in general*, I would recommend looking into a [*markdown* format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) (instead of plain HTML), such as used by SO. Then using an existing library to turn this into HTML, and use CSS to apply any additional styling. Of course, make sure to only allow the desired [markdown] operations.

Comment: Yes, nothing to be done with MySQL. You can use any editor to get raw output. For example you can use tinymce editor or wiswyg editor so that if you will add paragraph, you can get the same in the output and you can add the same in DB.

Answer (score 1):

If the user used the 'Enter' key to separate paragraphs then there are 'newline' characters in the text.  To render line breaks in HTML use `<br />`.  You can use `nl2br()` before you display the text.  This converts newline `\n` to `<br />`.